# Excluded code still showing in Code Coverage analysis

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit

I have a method which writes a structure list to a file and returns the count of structures in the list

```
[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]
public static int WriteFileFromTransactionsList(List<Transactions> transList = new List<Transactions>(), string outputFile)
{
    FileSystemCommands.WriteFileFromStringList(
        transList.Select(t => string.Format("ROC: {0}; 
        ClaimNumber: {1}; TranType: {2}; ItemClaimant: {3}{4}",
        t.ROC, t.ClaimNumber, t.TransCode, t.Coverage, t.Claimant)).ToList(),
        string.Format("{0}", outputFile));

    return transList.Count();
}
```

I have added the [ExclucdeFromCodeCoverage] tag because the FileSystemCommands.WriteFileFromStringList method is unit tested within the FileSystemCommands Unit Tests and the only thing which this method does which is not tested is return a count of the transList which will be zero if a null transList is passed;

I am also using a .runsettings file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>  
<!-- File name extension must be .runsettings -->  
<RunSettings>  
    <DataCollectionRunSettings>  
        <DataCollectors>  
            <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">  
                <Configuration>  
                    <CodeCoverage>  
<!--  
Additional paths to search for .pdb (symbol) files. Symbols must be found for modules to be instrumented.  
If .pdb files are in the same folder as the .dll or .exe files, they are automatically found. Otherwise, specify them here.  
Note that searching for symbols increases code coverage runtime. So keep this small and local.  
-->   
<!--             
                        <SymbolSearchPaths>                
                            <Path>C:\Users\User\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\ProjectX\bin\Debug</Path>  
                            <Path>\\mybuildshare\builds\ProjectX</Path>  
                        </SymbolSearchPaths>  
-->  

<!--  
About include/exclude lists:  
Empty "Include" clauses imply all; empty "Exclude" clauses imply none.  
Each element in the list is a regular expression (ECMAScript syntax). See http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2k3te2cs.aspx.  
An item must first match at least one entry in the include list to be included.  
Included items must then not match any entries in the exclude list to remain included.  
-->  
                         <!-- Match assembly file paths: -->  
                         <ModulePaths>  
                             <Include>  
                                 <ModulePath>.*\.exe$</ModulePath>   
                             </Include>  
                             <Exclude>  
                                 <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>  
                             </Exclude>  
                         </ModulePaths> 

                         <!-- Match attributes on any code element: -->  
                         <Attributes>  
                             <Exclude>  
                                <Attribute>^System\.Diagnostics\.CodeAnalysis\.ExcludeFromCodeCoverageAttribute$</Attribute>  
                             </Exclude>  
                         </Attributes>  

                         <!-- Match the company name property in the assembly: -->  
                         <CompanyNames>  
                             <Exclude>  
                                <CompanyName>.*microsoft.*</CompanyName>
                                 <CompanyName>.*fluentassertions*</CompanyName>
                             </Exclude>  
                         </CompanyNames>  

                         <!-- We recommend you do not change the following values: -->  
                        <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>True</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>  
                        <AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>True</AllowLowIntegrityProcesses>  
                        <CollectFromChildProcesses>True</CollectFromChildProcesses>  
                        <CollectAspDotNet>False</CollectAspDotNet>  
                    </CodeCoverage>  
                </Configuration>  
            </DataCollector>  
        </DataCollectors>  
    </DataCollectionRunSettings>  
</RunSettings>
```

However when I run the Code Coverage analysis from visual studio (I'm using testing framework NUnit 3) I get a report saying that his method is 100% not covered and is highlighting the transList.Select() part of the code.

Can anyone see why the Code Coverage analysis would be including this as it is in a method which is supposed to be excluded from code coverage?

Also I have noticed this in other methods which have the Exclude from code coverage tag.  It mostly picks up when I am using generics.

Comment: Try what is in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362699/excludefromcodecoverage-isnt-working-in-vs2012#15367804

Comment: @melle  I already have this in my .runsettings file.  I have tried it both by escaping the period and without escaping the period but to no avail

Comment: Chasing the mythical 100% code coverage I see, I had some fun chasing it too, but on large/complex application it will be a headache and probably a waste of time (added many test cases just to satisfy the analysis tool) at the end I gave up and accepted that not every line of code needs UnitTests

Comment: @HelderSepu No, we have a min code coverage of 80%.  I'm currently on 75% and the only things which aren't covered are these methods which shouldn't be appearing

Comment: If that 80% is not flexible you are on the same boat... In that case just add a test to the method in question to satisfy the analysis tool, by complexity of ```WriteFileFromTransactionsList``` it should take you just a few minutes to write a test for it.

Comment: Let's hope someone has experience with ```[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]``` and can clarify how to use it ...