# VSTS / VSTest not adhering to [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]

Tags: unit-testing, continuous-integration, azure-devops

I have just recently started using Continuous Integration with VSTS and I have set up a pipeline which includes the "Visual Studio Test" Task.

Within the task, there's an option to execute a code coverage scan as part of the test.

To ensure that my code coverage only covers MY code and have a) created a `.RunSettings` file to include only the assemblies I generate and b) there are some parts of the code with the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute.

Now, when execute `Analyze Code Coverage` from Visual Studio (2017 Enterprise, 15.7.4), everything works as I would expect, only my assembly gets analyzed and the code I have excluded is, errr, excluded.

However, when the VSTS pipeline is run, no such limitations are applied and ALL assemblies are tested and ALL code, including the specifically excluded code, which then results in a dramatic drop on the code-coverage %age.

Not sure where to go from here so hoping the S/O community can help.

**Update** - RunSettings file in use

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <!-- Configurations for data collectors -->
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*Tests.dll$</ModulePath>
                <ModulePath>.*moq.dll$</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
            <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>False</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>

    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an issue here: [RunSettings file not used in TFS VsTest task](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/8065), you can go and check the discussion about this issue.

As a workaround you can use below .RunSettings formats (add the `UseVerifiableInstrumentation = False`)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
  <DataCollectionRunSettings>
    <DataCollectors>
      <DataCollector friendlyName="Code Coverage" uri="datacollector://Microsoft/CodeCoverage/2.0" assemblyQualifiedName="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.DynamicCoverageDataCollector, Microsoft.VisualStudio.TraceCollector, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a">
        <Configuration>
          <CodeCoverage>
           <UseVerifiableInstrumentation>False</UseVerifiableInstrumentation>
            <ModulePaths>
              <Include>
                <ModulePath>.*\\MyProjectName.*\.dll$</ModulePath>
              </Include>
              <Exclude>
                <ModulePath>.*Tests.dll$</ModulePath>
              </Exclude>
            </ModulePaths>
          </CodeCoverage>
        </Configuration>
      </DataCollector>
    </DataCollectors>
  </DataCollectionRunSettings>
</RunSettings>
```

Just check **acesiddhu's** explanation:

> you are using visual studio test tools installer task in your
>   definition. in case that task is used useverifiable property needs to
>   be set to false because in xcopy mode we don't GAC the above dll
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.CodeCoverage.Shim (this is a dependency which
>   needs to be loaded when useverifiable is set to true)
>
> marking this property false ensures it doesn't use this particular
>   dll.

Comment: Well .. I've now got both Visual Studio and VSTS CI process to produce matching results but there's still a couple of issues.. 1. They both are still including the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` code and 2. On the CI build summary for code coverage, the %ag seems to include data from excluded assemblies therefore dropping the value .. Summary say 9.30% whereas the actual output says 14.65%

Comment: Interestingly, if I run Code Coverage in Visual Studio and un-tick the option to use the RunSettings file, then the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` is actually excluded and brings the %ag up to 17%

Comment: added RunSettings to main question

Comment: @ChrisHammond Check if this thread helps : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15362699/excludefromcodecoverage-isnt-working-in-vs2012

Comment: Yep... That's the one ... although the %ag on the summary page is different to the actual test results... Thanks for all your help Andy.